# Why is Xdebug still not appearing in phpinfo() or from php -v?

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I am running macOS sierra with php 5.6.24 as told from phpinfo() and followed the instructions [here](http://www.fieg.nl/installing-xdebug-on-mac-osx).Except for the last part which has been disabled for later versions of macOS from a google search. I didn't understand enough to know another way to "restart a web server" but I did `sudo apachectl stop`.

One peculiarity is that I didn't have a php.ini but a php.ini.default file along with a php.ini.default-5.2-previous and php.ini.default-previous. I choose to follow the tutorial with the php.ini.default.

Another was when I ran `locate xdebug.so` I go multiple results I'm guessing my previously installed MAMP(Although im not using MAMP at all atm) came with its own xdebug

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.45/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
```

Also tried

```
if(extension_loaded("xdebug")){
          echo"loaded";
        }else{
          echo"not loaded";
        }
```

and got not loaded

After running `apachectl stop` and `apachectl start` I did `php -v` but didn't get `with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans` I have been trying to install this for hours now, someone help?

Comment: What does `ls -la $(which php)` give? What about `php --ini` (this one should give an xdebug result I guess, at least when using php installed with homebrew, which I recommend, it does)

Comment: for `ls -la $(which php)` I get `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10764144 Sep 13  2016 /usr/bin/php` and for `php --ini` I get                               `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`